# Error opening up facebook live. Works on other accounts

Tags: html, facebook, google-chrome, stream, live

[image: screen shot of issue]

Hi all,

I am looking to record a live stream/video post on Facebook. I can see the 'Live' button when posting. Once clicked it takes you to this page (see screenshot) then gives this error "something went wrong, but we're working to fix it as soon as we can". Been like this for 2 days now.

This happens in Chrome, Edge and on Iphone. I can record a live stream using other facebook accounts on these formats though. I am using windows 10 if that helps?

The page address is takes you to is:

https://www.facebook.com/live/producer/?target_id=100050905598457&source=CAMERA&entry_point=feedx_sprouts

I know it's not specifically a programming issue, however I wondered if any coders could decipher what issues there may be. The only difference I can see is that the working account has upgraded to the 'new' facebook layout. Unfortunately, I can't update the facebook account I need to actually stream from yet, as facebook are still rolling this out.

Many Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to a programming problem.  Your question may be more on-topic here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com  Though you are of course encouraged to visit that community's tour and help pages first.

Comment: Fair enough....